# Call django task from button click in nuxt application via rest api

Tags: python, django, vue.js, django-rest-framework, nuxt.js

I have a python wrapper that updates data from a third party api in my backend.
The background task cannot fetch all the data without taking params in order to filter down each call and return filtered batches. I don't want to have these background tasks running periodically because I would like to limit my api calls.

What I'm trying to do is use button click to make a post request from my nuxt frontend and trigger a function that will fetch the data and update a model in in the view.

When I make the post request from nuxt I get data to the backend and saving to the models.

What doesn't happen is events function being called and saving to the events model.

I'm not getting any error but I would've expected the rest of the code within the view would be called before being 201 created.

How can I get the rest of the code to execute or even pass a parameter each time the button is clicked in nuxt to?

```
 events =  api.market_data.get_events(sport_ids=['my_param'])
```

**nuxtapp**

```
<template>

<div>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark" v-on:click="get_tennis">get_tennis</button>

  </div>
</template>

<script>

  export default {
  
  methods: {
    get_tennis () {
      this.$axios.post('api/sportsid/', 
        { 
          sport_id: "9",
          sport_name: "tennis"
        }
      );
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

**views.py**

```
from client import get_client
from .models import *
from

class SportsViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    
    queryset = SportsId.objects.all()
    serializer_class = SportsIdSerializer

    @action(detail=False,methods=['POST'])
    def add_sports(self, request: Request) -> Response:

        api = get_client()
        events =  api.market_data.get_events(sport_ids=['4'])

        for event in events:
            event_name = event["name"]
            ev, created = Event.objects.update_or_create(event_id=event_id)
            ev.event_name = event_name
            ev.save()
            
            serializer = SportsIdSerializer(data=request.data)
            serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
            serializer.save(post=self.get_object())
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

**serializer.py**

```
class SportsIdSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = SportsId
        fields = '__all__' 

class EventSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
     class Meta:
        model = Event
        fields = '__all__'
```

**models.py**

```
class SportsId(models.Model):
    sport_id = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=15)
    sport_name = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=50)

class Event(models.Model):
    event_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

from rest_framework import routers
from apimb.views import *

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register('sportsid',MatchbookSportsViewSet)

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('api/', include(router.urls)),
    path('api/auth/', include('djoser.urls')),
    path('api/auth/', include('djoser.urls.authtoken')),]
```

Comment: Why you are not using then(catch) in axios to get response from the server?

Comment: @Musulmon the post request works so a catch would not show me anything from what I believe.

Comment: @Musulmon I added a catch to log an error and have none.

Comment: you are just requesting to the server, but not wait while the server send back the response. For that you you should use then block of request. If the server sends back the response with status 200, it means that you model has been saved or updated.